# PHP, MYSQL Creating a blog comment system

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on developing a blogging system. For the most part I have the blog done, just creating the scripts to allow users to post comments to each blog. My PHP select code is getting an error along the lines of

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC WHERE blogID = 6' at line 1.

The full code of my SQL statement is:

```
SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments   
ORDER BY commentID LIMIT 1 DESC WHERE blogID = '.$row['postID'];`
```

I am aware that this current statement is susceptible to SQL Injections, and have tried using tokens to ensure I am protected from that.

the `$row['postiD']` is from a previous SQL statement that was ran to display the actual blog post. This is intended to go on the main page, where I don't need to display the actual comment text, but rather just the number of comments that are on that particular blog. I can post the full code if needed.

Okay, I updated my SQL statement and fixed that issue. However, the page is not displaying the `commentID` number, and `$e` is not getting executed, nor do I get any errors in my apache2 log.

```
$query = "SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments WHERE blogID ':postid' ORDER BY commentID DESC LIMIT 1";
$query_params = array(':postid' => $row['postID']);
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // dont echo $e on production site
    die($e->getMessage());
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
comments
```

Comment: 'SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments ORDER BY commentID LIMIT 1 DESC WHERE blogID = '.$row['postID'];..query misses a quote correct it and check again for errors:  '.$row['postID'].'

Comment: Your order seems off have you tried `'SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments WHERE blogID = '.$row['postID'].' ORDER BY commentID DESC LIMIT 1';  `

Comment: SO works on a 1 question per post basis. If you have new question, create a new post, referencing back to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `WHERE` case just after select:

```
'SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments 
 WHERE blogID = '.$row['postID'].' ORDER BY commentID DESC LIMIT 1'
```

To prevent SQL-injections use `PDO` and prepared statements : (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

You really need to learn how we create `select ,order, where and limit` statement in SQL

Your query would be

```
"SELECT `commentID`, `blogID` FROM `blog_comments`  WHERE `blogID` = '".$row['postID']."' ORDER BY `commentID` DESC LIMIT 1" ;
```

Read  [Tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Also read [How can I prevent SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You have written wrong query

```
'SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments WHERE blogID = '.$row['postID'].' ORDER BY commentID DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query elements sequence seems wrong , Please follow below query sequence :

```
'SELECT commentID, blogID FROM blog_comments WHERE blogID = '.$row['postID'].' ORDER BY commentID DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Require to set **ORDER BY & LIMIT** after **WHERE** clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `commentID`, `blogID` FROM `blog_comments` WHERE blogID = $row['postID'] order by `commentID` DESC limit 1
```